# Why are my rostests giving me a std::bad_alloc error?

Tags: ros, rostest, rosconsole, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm porting my ROS code from Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 to using the newer ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04. What I've noticed is that, in one particular test, I will occasionally get a `std::bad_alloc` exception thrown:

> C++ exception with description "std::bad_alloc" thrown in the test fixture's constructor

#### Behaviour

- Error only occurs when there are more than one `TEST_F()` functions.
- Console output stops displaying after first `TEST_F()` is run.

#### Code

```
class TransitionClientTest : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
  void SetUp()
  {
    query_client_.Initialize(node_handle_);
  }

private:
  ros::NodeHandle node_handle_
  QueryClientType query_client_;
};

TEST_F(TransitionClientTest, TestQuery)
{
  ROS_INFO("TestQuery running");
  EXPECT_EQ(query_client_.Query(), 1);
}

TEST_F(TransitionClientTest, TestPort)
{
  ROS_INFO("TestPort running");  // Won't get displayed
  EXPECT_EQ(query_client_.Port(), 99);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "TransitionClientTest");
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  int result = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  return result;
}
```

The *TestPort* test will often cause a `std::bad_alloc` error. If it doesn't, then it will not display the `ROS_INFO` statement.

The test is defined in my CMakeLists in a `add_rostest_gtest()` call.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259215/why-are-my-rostests-giving-me-a-std::bad_alloc-error?/) by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 156 on 2017-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason behind this bug is related to a bug reported in roscomm: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/688

To fix this, I changed the int main function to:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "TransitionClientTest");
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  ros::NodeHandle nh("~");
  int result = RUN_ALL_TESTS();
  return result;
}
```

When there was a `NodeHandle` that persisted, it prevented the `std::bad_alloc` exception and gave me console output in the proceeding cases.

---

Originally posted by [cpagravel](https://answers.ros.org/users/29737/cpagravel/) with karma: 156 on 2017-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2